# How can i format(bold) a word within a text?

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

In the code below, i want to make the value of "$_counter" bold. How to accomplish that?

```
new Text(
  'You have pushed the button $_counter time${_counter > 1
      ? 's'
      : ''}',
  style: new TextStyle(fontSize: fontSize),
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
),
```

I want output to be something like this:

You have pushed the button **2** times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use `RichTextfor` that

```
new RichText(
textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          text: new TextSpan(
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            children: <TextSpan>[
              new TextSpan(text: 'You have pushed the button '),
              new TextSpan(text: '$_counter', style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              new TextSpan(text: ' time!'),
            ],
          ),
        )
```

[image]

Comment: I have already referred this example but i want to know how to apply it in my particular type of code!

Comment: Can you please help me with closing of all the braces in your updated code?

Comment: sure what your problem ?

Comment: One more question, how to add textAlign in the above code?

Comment: there is a property for that in rich text
i updated my answer again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174926/discussion-between-hetvi-gandhi-and-raouf-rahiche).

Answer (score 2):

You can try appending Text Widgets in a row to achieve this.

```
final prefixText = Text('You have clicked the button');

final counterText = Text(' $_counter', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),);

final suffixText = Text(' times');

return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[prefixText, counterText, suffixText],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

NOTE: Though you get the desired output using this, I think the answer of @Raouf Rahiche is more appropriate.

Comment: I am sorry if i sound silly but i wanted to clear where to define prefixText, counterText and suffixText in whole file?

Comment: You can define it in 'build" method which will eventually return Scaffold.

Answer (score 0):

You can fontWeight for it.

child: new Text(
              StringUtil.FORGOT_PASSWORD,
              style: new TextStyle(
                  color: const Color(0xFF8C919E),
                  fontSize: 12.0,
                  letterSpacing: 0.3,
                  **fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),**
            ),